# GitHub actions setup-python stopped working

Tags: python, github-actions

Below is my workflow file, which worked previously forever and I've not changed anything.

```
env:
  PYTHON_VERSION: '3.8.9'

jobs:
  build:
    name: build 
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - uses: actions/setup-python@v3
      with:
        python-version: ${{ env.PYTHON_VERSION }}
    - run: mkdir file-icons product-icons
    - run: python3 -m translate
    - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
      with:
        name: build
        path: |
          file-icons/
          product-icons/
          thumbnails/
          *.md
          package.json
```

today it decided to stop working 
`Error: Version 3.8.9 with arch x64 not found`
[image]

this is with debug logging on

`##[debug]x64===x64 && linux===linux` makes no sense to me, it found a match and then just moved on
[image]

what it was before
[image]

Comment: For all such you should report to the action author(s), https://github.com/actions/setup-python/issues

Comment: The current version of `actions/setup-python` is `@v4`. Try updating and see if you get the same error with that version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved. GitHub actions recently updated ubuntu-latest from 20.04 to 22.04

- https://github.blog/changelog/2022-08-09-github-actions-ubuntu-22-04-is-now-generally-available-on-github-hosted-runners/
- https://github.com/actions/runner-images/issues/6399

certain versions of python is not yet supported by setup-python action on 22.04 (and currently they are not looking to support old python versions such as 3.8.9)

#### Solutions:

option one - set ubuntu to 20.0.4 (the suggested option according to the runner image issue on GitHub https://github.com/actions/runner-images/issues/6399)

option two - use python 3.8.12 or newer

Comment: I faced the same problem.. 3.8.9 is pretty old, it might never be supported with the Ubuntu 22.04 image. I think the solution is to bump Python up, or lock Ubuntu to 20.04 if you really can't bump Python.

Comment: Python 3.8.12 is the oldest 3.8 available with the Ubuntu 22.04 image.